# Definition of holomorphic function such that for positive real $ x $, $ f\left(x\right)=x^{x} $

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to define on the region $ D\subset\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\leq0} $ (which is simply connected), a holomorphic function $ f:D\to \mathbb{C} $ such that for positive real $ x $ we have $ f\left(x\right)=x^{x} $.

Now my first intuition was to define $ f\left(z\right)=e^{z\log\left(z\right)} $, for some branch of the complex log, and then for any other holomorphic function that satisfies $ g(x)=x^x $ for positive real $ x $, we have by uniqueness theorem ($ \mathbb{R_{>0}} $ is a non discrete set) that $g=f$.

My questions are:

1. How can I be sure that for any real positive $ x $ the complex log and the real log agrees? Is it true for any branch of log, or just for a branch of log defined as the following :

for $ z=|z|e^{iarg(z)} $:
$$ \log\left(z\right)=\log\left(|z|\right)+i\left(\arg\left(z\right)+2\pi k\right) $$
and the specific $ log $ I ment is the log that we get by choosing $k=0$.
($ \log(|z|) $ here is the real log function as we know from real analysis).

2.If the answer to 1 is that positive log and complex log agrees at real positive numbers regardless of the log branch, how can I be sure that uniquness indeed exists? How can I be sure that one cannot find another branch of log which would satisfy those equations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal branch of logarithm, which I denote by $\operatorname{Log}z$ is well defined and analytic in your region. For any  real number $x$ we have $\operatorname{Log} x=\ln |x|+i 0=\ln |x|$  by the definition of $\operatorname{Log}z$. So $f(z)=e^{z\operatorname{Log}z}$ serves the purpose.

Suppose $g(z)=e^{z\log z}$ where $\log  z$ is another  (continuous) branch of logarithm with $g(x)=x^{x}$ for all $x >0$. Then $\operatorname{Log}z =\log z+2n\pi i$ where $n$ is an integer (independent of $z$ by continuity). But then $e^{2n\pi i x}=1$ for all $x >0$ and this implies that $n$ must be $0$ . So the principal branch is the only admissible one.